# how do you summarize a pandas data frame by groupby in special format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame as this:

```
print(df)

Env location lob    grid row server   model   make   slot   ports  connected disabled
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2 Server123 Hitachi Stor   1      3        1         5
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2 Server123 Hitachi Stor   2      2        3         3
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2 Server123 Hitachi Stor   3      0        0         2
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2 Server123 Hitachi Stor   4      8        7         1
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM Mfa        1      6        5         0
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM Mfa        2      8        4         0
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM Mfa        3     12        4         0
Dev  EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM Mfa        4     10        2         0
```

I need to summarize this table and sum the numeric values group by Server. The summary table needs to look like this. I need to print out the string values from the last row of the group by (Server), no need to add the slot column. Other columns needs to be summed and addedd to the last row of the group by. Need to insert a space between each group.

```
print(df2)

Env location lob    grid row server   model   make   slot   ports  connected disabled
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2  Server123 Hitachi Stor   1      3        1         5
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2  Server123 Hitachi Stor   2      2        3         3
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2  Server123 Hitachi Stor   3      0        0         2
Prod USA     Market AB3 bc2  Server123 Hitachi Stor   4      8        7         1
Total USA    Market  AB3 bc2  Server123 Model Stor         13       11        11

Dev   EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM    Mfa        1      6        5         0
Dev   EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM    Mfa        2      8        4         0
Dev   EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM    Mfa        3     12        4         0
Dev   EMEA    Ins.   AB6 bc4 Serverabc IBM    Mfa        4     10        2             
Total EMEA    Ins    AB6 bc4  Serverabc IBM   Mfa             36        15        0
```

I have tried this:

```
df2=df1.groupby('Server').sum()
```

this adds the values and shows each server in the data frame. I need to add the sum values at the end of each group in data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
all_groups = []
for _, g in df.groupby("server"):
    x = g.loc[:, "slot":].sum().to_frame().T
    x["Env"] = "Total"
    x["slot"] = ""

    g = pd.concat([g, x]).ffill()
    g = pd.concat([g, pd.DataFrame({"server": [np.nan]})]).fillna("")
    all_groups.append(g)

print(pd.concat(all_groups, ignore_index=True)[:-1])
```

Prints:

```
      Env location     lob grid  row     server    model  make slot ports connected disabled
0    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    1   3.0       1.0      5.0
1    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    2   2.0       3.0      3.0
2    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    3   0.0       0.0      2.0
3    Prod      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor    4   8.0       7.0      1.0
4   Total      USA  Market  AB3  bc2  Server123  Hitachi  Stor       13.0      11.0     11.0
5                                                                                           
6     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    1   6.0       5.0      0.0
7     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    2   8.0       4.0      0.0
8     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    3  12.0       4.0      0.0
9     Dev     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa    4  10.0       2.0      0.0
10  Total     EMEA    Ins.  AB6  bc4  Serverabc      IBM   Mfa       36.0      15.0      0.0
```

Comment: this is really good. Thank you. quick question, If I wanted to do calculate the avg on one of the columns. For example column "disabled", print out the avg rather than sum 22/5=4.4, how can I do this

Comment: @user1471980 You can add `x["disabled"] = g["disabled"].mean()` just before the `x["Env"] = "Total"` line.